# Unable to find type or namespace signinmanager tuser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am having issues with making a get request inside my GetAll method in the controller.

```
        [HttpGet("GetAll")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllTasks()
        {
            String? userName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
            Account? user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName!);
            if (user != null)
            {
                List<Task> tasks = await _taskRepository.GetAll();
                return Ok(tasks.Where(t => t.UserId == user.Id));
            }
            return NotFound();
        }
```

While debugging my application I am seeing an error message that says unable to find type or namespace signinmanager TUser. I tried injecting signin manager in my controller, but still having the same issue.

```
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TaskController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ITaskRepository _taskRepository;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly UserManager<Account> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<Account> _signInManager;
        public TaskController(ITaskRepository taskRepository, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, UserManager<Account> userManager, SignInManager<Account> signInManager)
        {
            _taskRepository = taskRepository;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }
```

My program.cs looks like this.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<Account>()
    .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<Account>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer().AddIdentityCookies();
```

here are the namespaces I am using

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using Core.Entities;
using Core.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using TaskManagementApi.Models;
using Task = Core.Entities.Task;
```

Comment: Which versions of .NET and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity are you using? The identity stuff does have a habit of splitting up and jumping around packages between versions

Comment: I was using microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore version 8.0.0

Comment: I am going to try it with version 7.0.13

Comment: ok I'll add sign in manager as a service

Comment: Registering signinmanager as a service does not fix it either

Comment: I changed the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore as well as all related entity framework packages to version 7.0.13

Comment: How about the issue when you using the version 7.0.13 ?

Comment: Could you try to remove comment `builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<Account>()
    .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<Account>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();`, and use `builder.Services.AddIdentity<Account, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
`.

Comment: I don't want to use builder.services.addidentity() because I don't have a use for roles in my application

Comment: Ever since I switched to version 7.0.13 for all the appropriate packages I still have the same issue

Comment: Could you share more error details? Or you can create a brand new project which can reproduce the issue and share with us. I am willing to investigate it.